# Why do React apps have so many try-catch blocks?

Tags: reactjs, try-catch

Pretty much for the entirety of my career I've treated try-catch blocks as a nonstarter. Now that I've (unfortunately) worked with several React apps, much to my dismay there have been *hundreds* of try catch blocks used pretty much everywhere. What is this madness; given all the capabilities of linters nowadays how is this something not disallowed?

Comment: This is not really a concrete technically question, is it? Could you provide some code snippet that uses try catch so people could support you with your problem? I cannot think of any React specific code that would require try catch blocks other than fetching data. Is this a react specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Error Boundaries?

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

There are some patterns in React to help with error handling.